# What is wrong with this go switch statement?

Tags: go

Can anybody see why this switch won't work?

```
func main() {

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

    fmt.Print(text)

    switch text {
    case "a":
        fmt.Print("A\n")
    case "b":
        fmt.Print("B\n")
    case "c":
        fmt.Print("C\n")
    default:
        fmt.Print("DEFAULT\n")
    }
}
```

In this statement, the default value is always returned yet when hard coding the switch expression, the switch block works as it should. Looking at the ReadString() func code, it returns a string so I can't see any reason for my example to not work.

Am I doing something wrong?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text consists of two bytes: `fmt.Print(len(text))` is 2 and `fmt.Print(len("a"))` is one.

You the second symbol is invisible and you can try to remove it with `text = strings.TrimSpace(text)`.

Comment: @donpisci this is something that is hard to spot.

Answer (score 3):

Per the [docs](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader.ReadString):

> ReadString reads until the first occurrence of delim in the input, returning a string containing the data up to **and including** the delimiter.

Therefore you can do something like:

```
reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
delim := byte('\n')
text, _ := reader.ReadString(delim)

switch text = strings.TrimRight(text, string(delim)); text {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`text` contains "\n", you need to either match it or trim.

```
switch text = strings.TrimSpace(text); text {
case "a":
    fmt.Println("A")
case "b":
    fmt.Println("B")
case "c":
    fmt.Println("C")
default:
    fmt.Println("DEFAULT: " + text)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of \n text has space. you have to remove it by strings.Trimspace() method.

package main

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    text, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Print(text)
    
    switch strings.TrimSpace(text) {
    case "a":
        fmt.Print("A\n")
    case "b":
        fmt.Print("B\n")
    case "c":
        fmt.Print("C\n")
    default:
        fmt.Print("DEFAULT\n")
    }
}
```